# Is there a possibility to install Ruby with all deps like zlib without active internet access?

Tags: ruby, devops, rbenv, fluentd, sles

the question seems to be weird, but it's a part of long story to install Fluentd on sles11 sp4, actually.
I've seen success story of Fluentd on sles11 sp3 here, by @ab77

https://serverfault.com/questions/539307/installing-fluentd-kibana-elastic-search-on-suse-enterprise-linux-11/540521#540521

Unfortunately, I can't follow the way above because of my company security policy  : git clone from github via https is disabled, so all dynamic deps via rbenv fail.

So I got an idea to install Ruby 2.1.0 (Fluentd requirements) from an isolated package on JBoss of my company, which should contain all the dependencies. 
For the moment I'm struggling with numerous dependencies and not sure if this is possible at all or not (I'm completely new in Ruby).

If you were facing something similar, could you please share your experience?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: There is some tutorial for RVM (Ruby version manager) https://rvm.io/rvm/offline 
I've seen companies putting gems to their own gem servers and installing them from there directly https://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some tutorial for RVM (Ruby version manager) rvm.io/rvm/offline 
I've seen companies putting gems to their own gem servers and installing them from there directly guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server